# Create Alphanumeric Range in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, range

I tried using [range()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) in this way:

```
echo '<pre>'. print_r(range('A1', 'A4'), 1) .'</pre>';
```

to create this array:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
```

But it actually returned:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
)
```

Reading the docs confirms this kind of use isn't the intended use.

I could use this code to get my desired result:

```
$myRange = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'];
```

But it feels inefficient, with 4, it's not so bad but the task becomes Herculian when it goes into triple digits. Is there something built-in to PHP that handles alphanumeric range generation?

Thanks,

Thanks

Comment: Why not create integer range and then add prefix of `A` for each elememt?

Comment: From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) "Character sequence values are limited to a length of one. If a length greater than one is entered, only the first character is used." so it is doing exactly what it is supposed to.

Comment: @dWinder that's not a bad idea actually!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with [array_map](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-map.php) and range:

```
$prefix = "A";
$arr = array_map(function ($e) use ($prefix) { return $prefix . strval($e);}, range(1,4));
```

Or as a function:

```
function alphanumericRange($prefix, $start, $end)
{
    return array_map(function ($e) use ($prefix) {return $prefix . strval($e);}, range($start, $end));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this way with [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)?

```
<?php
function addA($sValue) {
    return 'A'.$sValue;
}

$range = range(1,10);
$alphabet_range = array_map("addA", $range);
print_r($alphabet_range);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/kGmTL

Comment: I like it, but defo's prefer dWinder's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply get `range(0,4)` of number array variable and use `Join(",A")` function and use split with `explode()` function as show below

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r(explode(",","A".Join(",A",range(0, 4))));
```